# How do I embed EJS code in static Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, express, ejs

I am using Nodejs and ExpressJS .

I have an HTML page , which has a Javascript file being referred to .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/game.js"></script>
```

I have not embedded all the Javascript into the HTML page itself because its too big .

Now I need my Javascript ( game.js )  to access some of the variables being passed by the controller .  I want to do something like this -

```
var max_players = parseInt("<%= table.total_players %>");
console.log("<%= table.name %>")
```

I am passing the table variable while rendering the page .

```
 exports.index = function(req,res){

//code
res.render('mytable', {table: table });

    };
```

But this obviously doesnt work because the JS file is being rendered as a static file . 
How do I go about if I need to make these variables accessible to the Javascript ?

I read somewhere that this can be achieved by renaming Game.js to Game.ejs . But where do I put the Game.js file ( so that its rendered properly and dynamically ? )

If there are any other ways to achieve this , please also let me know .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the simplest option would be to output the globals you need from `table` (or `table` itself) in another `<script>` before `game.js`:

```
<script>
   var max_players = <%- JSON.stringify(table.total_players) %>;
   console.log(<%- JSON.stringify(table.name) %>);

   /* Alternative:
     var table = <%- JSON.stringify(table) %>;
     var max_players = table.total_players;
     console.log(table.name);
   */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/game.js"></script>
```

Note the use of `<%- ... %>` vs. `<%= ... %>`, which will skip HTML-encoding the output as that can cause syntax errors in.

Using `JSON.stringify()` here takes advantage  of the syntax relation between JSON and JavaScript. The values will be written as JSON data server-side, but parsed as [JavaScript literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals) client-side.

---

If you want to run `game.js` itself through EJS, you can move it into your `./views` directory, add a route for it, and `res.render()` it.

Note that you'll need to set the `Content-Type` as the assumed value will be `text/html`, which could some browsers will refuse to parse.

```
// ~/views/game-js.ejs

var max_players = <%- JSON.stringify(table.total_players) %>;
console.log(<%- JSON.stringify(table.name) %>);

// ...
```

```
app.get('/javascripts/game.js', function (req, res) {
    // code
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
    res.render('game-js', { table: table });
});
```

---

Another option would be to have `game.js` make a request for `table`. You can see an example of this in [a previous edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18413831/2) of this post.

Comment: I usually use one client-side variable for this...   `clientData = JSON.stringify({ table:table });`  for anything meant to be exposed to the client.. towards the top of my html, in the head... then it's available... in .Net I'll use an HttpContext.Current.Items['__ClientData__'] to store a dynamic object and expose it... in Node,  it's usually explicit with the model.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski - Thanks a lot . Quite descriptive .